# Rspec for REST API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

Im trying to implement rspec for a http call... But I have not succeeded so far..

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("secured site url", "443")
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE  
response = http.get("/query params",initheader = {'Accept' =>'application/xml'})
return response
```

I would need an rspec for this..Though Im new to this, I tried many ways but it says expected: 1 time received: 0 times

Here is all what I have written :

```
it "should be success" do
  @mock_http = mock("http")
  @mock_http.should_receive(:new).with("secured site url")
end
```

Please correct me if Im wrong.. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you have to activate the method in which the new statement is called so your code should look something like:

```
it "should be success" do
  @mock_http = mock("http")
  Net::HTTP.should_receive(:new).with("secured site url", "443")
  some_method
end

def some_method
  http = Net::HTTP.new("secured site url", "443")
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE  
  response = http.get("/query params",initheader = {'Accept' =>'application/xml'})
  return response 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I actually tried to stub the response and then use it..I also tried this but it says Failure/Error:     http.use_ssl = true
NoMethodError: undefined method `use_ssl=' for nil:NilClass